# Regex hard to find

Tags: regex

I'd like to build a regex which will be run on the following elements:

```
test.stuff;visibility:=reexport,
test.stuff;bundle-version="0.0.0";visibility:=reexport,
test.stuff;bundle-version="0.0.0"
test.stuff,
test.stuff
```

The aim of my regex is to either **replace bundle-version="0.0.0" by bundle-version="1.2.3"** or to **add bundle-version="1.2.3"**.

After replacement it should produce the following elements:

```
test.stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3";visibility:=reexport,
test.stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3";visibility:=reexport,
test.stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3"
test.stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3",
test.stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3"
```

Currently I have the following regex:

```
(test.*?)([;]+bundle.*?)?([;,]+.*)
```

With this replacement pattern:

```
$1;bundle-version="1.2.3"$3
```

But it doesn't work for these two:

```
test.stuff;bundle-version="0.0.0"   --> becomes test.stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3";bundle-version="0.0.0"
test.stuff    --> not matched
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: the regex should only match lines starting with "test.stuff"

Comment: "But it doesn't work for these two". What does it do for those two?

Comment: @mad-physicist test.stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3";bundle-version="0.0.0"
and nothing (not matched)

Comment: Update your question with the pertinent information by clicking the edit button. Don't put info that would be useful to everyone reading the question into the comments.

Comment: @mad-physicist right, thx!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I ask because if it's Java, for example, this would be much easier with a two-step process.

Comment: It's aimed at being an ant one-liner replacement but the syntax matches  http://regexr.com/ rules (and is easily adaptable to ant's one)

Comment: It is not possible to use a one liner in cases when you need to replace with different replacement patterns.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew in my case you mean either add or replace depending on the context?

Comment: I cannot think of a backreference based approach for now, but if you manage it, you will get your one-liner.

Comment: I would not use a regular expression. I would split the record and analyze the fields

Comment: @Magnetron's answer does the job perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in C#/LinqPad:

```
string s = @"test.stuff;visibility:=reexport,
test.stuff;bundle-version=""0.0.0"";visibility:=reexport,
test.stuff;bundle-version=""0.0.0""
test.stuff,
test.stuff";

string pat = "(test[^;,\n]*)([;,]+bundle[^;,\n]*)?([;,]*.*)?";
string rep ="$1;bundle-version=\"1.2.3\"$3";

string result = Regex.Replace(s,pat,rep)
```

Edit: added \n to first group to avoid capturing a line after last "test.stuff" occurrence.

Comment: Works better but if you add a new line with "org.eclipse.ocl;visibility:=reexport," inside after "test.stuff" it also matches this new line, I'll try to adapt your regex !

Comment: Oh wait, it removes completely line 3 "test.stuff;bundle-version="0.0.0"" :D

Comment: great! adding a "\n" to the first group seems to be fine on regexer, I'll try with my real code :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two times:
1. replace `bundle-version="0.0.0"` par `bundle-version="1.2.3"`
2. replace `stuff(?!;bun)` par  `stuff;bundle-version="1.2.3"`

Comment: I'd perfer if this is possible a one-liner as I'm using it inside an ant replacement task and I don't to crawl the file twice.